# SharePoint SPListItemCollection ReorderItems

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

does anyone know how to use the SPListItemCollection ReorderItems method?  I cannot seem to find sufficent documentation on this method.  What I want to do is order the list  in decending order by date.  I am not sure what the required values are, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.reorderitems.aspx,  thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

the link you stated gives you all the information you need.
You can get more info from refactoring:

Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.dll in the ReorderPage class' BtnSave_Click event.

Probably, the issue you are having has to do with the fact that the list in question needs the allow ordering set to true. google for this, or check [this url](http://webborg.blogspot.com/2008/03/reordering-items-in-data-view.html) if still working.